# Ruby Implementing merge_sort algorithm leaving off elements from input array

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to implement a merge sort function into my app. It takes an array as an input, sorts it, and outputs the sorted array.

```
def sort(list)
  swapped = true
  sorted_list = []

  slice_count = list.size.to_i
  chunked_list = list.each_slice(slice_count).to_a.each{ |element| element.fill nil, slice_count, 0 }.transpose.map(&:compact)

  while swapped do
    swapped = false

    (slice_count-1).times do |i|
      if chunked_list[i][0] > chunked_list[i+1][0]
        chunked_list[i], chunked_list[i+1] = chunked_list[i+1], chunked_list[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
    break if !swapped
  end

  (slice_count-1).times do |i|
    sorted_list.push(chunked_list[i][0])
  end

  puts "Sorted list (merge): #{sorted_list}"
end
```

My issue arises from getting the input array. 
Running merge.sort([0, 3, 8, 5, 4, 9, 22]) outputs a sorted array WITHOUT the 0 and 22: `Sorted list (merge): [3, 4, 5, 8, 9]`

Debugging and returning the 'list' variable in pry gives me `[3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 22]`, which includes the 22 not present in the final output, but still excluding the 0 element from the input array. Why is it not taking the full array?

Comment: One question I have on this is if this function is really considered a merge sort? After the while loop it breaks the array into [[0], [3], [4], [5], [8], [9], [22]]. Shouldn't this be broken down into 2 arrays  [[0, 3, 4], [5, 8, 9, 22]], to be considered a merge sort?

Comment: There are two problems with your merge sort: 1) it's a bubble sort, not a merge sort; 2) an off-by-one error.

Comment: Right, but doesn't a merge sort break into 2, then 3, and so on until each element is in it's own array? And once they are all broken into individual chunks, you compare? @JörgWMittag

Comment: @DavidGross Couldn't seem to tag you in the above comment ^

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove - 1 on (slice_count).times do

```
def sort(list)
  swapped = true
  sorted_list = []

  slice_count = list.size.to_i
  chunked_list = list.each_slice(slice_count).to_a.each{ |element| element.fill nil, slice_count, 0 }.transpose.map(&:compact)

  while swapped do
    swapped = false

    (slice_count-1).times do |i|
      if chunked_list[i][0] > chunked_list[i+1][0]
        chunked_list[i], chunked_list[i+1] = chunked_list[i+1], chunked_list[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
    break if !swapped
  end

  (slice_count).times do |i|
    sorted_list.push(chunked_list[i][0])
  end

  puts "Sorted list (merge): #{sorted_list}"
end

Sorted list (merge): [0, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 22]
```

Comment: this looks a lot like bubble sort, are you sure it's merge sort?